# How do you see when memory was released in Instruments 8.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode-instruments

I've seen old screen shots of previous versions of instruments and there appear to be calls to 'free' along with calls to 'malloc' in the Allocations list.

This doesn't seem to be the case anymore.

I have tried not 'excluding' free events, but that doesn't appear to show `free` calls either.

[image]

How do you see when memory was freed now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to configure Instruments to keep the free events. First, make sure the Discard events for freed memory checkbox is not selected.

[image]

Second, set the allocation lifespan to Created and Destroyed.

[image]

To see free events in Instruments, you must drill down to a specific memory address. Instruments does not provide a list of free events. In the allocations summary, move the mouse cursor over a category. A button with an arrow will appear.

[image]

Click that button to see a list of memory allocations for that category. Move the mouse cursor over a memory address to bring up another with an arrow.

[image]

Click the button to see all the memory events for that address. This is where you find the free events.

[image]

Comment: I updated my answer. If the updated answer doesn't show free events for you, update your question with what you are expecting to see and what you are seeing.